# Update a new binary for existing one before available date on app store iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have a doubt before I upload my binary to App Store for review process.

Say I will upload my binary for review on 10 Jan and set the availability date to 10 Feb.

Let's say the app gets approved and status is changed to "Ready for sale".

But there are some under construction updates to be approved which might be implemented before the availability date?

So, can I update a new binary for review or do I have to wait until the availability date?

I presume I should be able to because I read in the apple docs that I can update a new binary once the status turns to "Ready for Sale". So this question is just to confirm my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Once your previous binary is ready for sale or developer rejected you can upload a new binary.

> You can add a new version of an app when the current version’s status
>   is Ready for Sale or Developer Removed from Sale. The new app version
>   goes through the same review process as the first version.
>
> Note:  If you find a problem with the binary whose status is Waiting
>   for Review or In Review, you can remove the binary from review and
>   upload a revised version of the app without starting a new version.

Reference [Replacing Your App With A New Version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You can update the binary before available date, but it will be again reviewed by Apple

Comment: Yea , No worries about the reviewing again. Thanks for confirming.